# JQuery UI dialog not working when declared in index.cshtml but works in partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using JQuery UI dialog for CRUD in my application. Dialog is declared as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $(".openDialog").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();


            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Add Student',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 650,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,

                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("/Projekti/UnosuProjekat")
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },

                buttons: {
                    "Delete all items": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

When i put this code in index.cshtml that render partial view where i need dialog, it's not working. 
When i put it inside partial view where button that execute dialog actually is declared, everything works fine.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: How do you render your partial view? You could try to check if the #dialog-edit is null or undefined before running the dialog.

Comment: @Html.Partial("_partial", Model, null). When i open source view in FF, script is shown there in both cases, just not working when not physically inside _partial...

Comment: ok, just had to rule out that you did it with ajax;) Like i mentioned, try to check if the dialog-edit is null or undefined first, that might explain more.

Comment: I'm actually using ajax.actionlink to create ".openDialog" link, and "#dialog-edit" is an empty div declared inside "_partial"

Comment: So that explains it then. When using ajax calls, you render the partialview when the link is hit. Which happens after $(document).ready. When you have the scriptcode in the partialview, it works because the partialview will hit its "document.ready" state when the request finish.

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand that... I have index.cshtml. Inside index, there's call to partial("_p1") where ajax.actionlink is rendered, and that ajax.actionlink has onclick where jquery is executed to call another partial view that will be on jquery ui dialog.

Comment: The Ajax.ActionLink sends an httprequest, that renders your partialview, containing the dialog-edit div. It means that when you load your page, it will be loaded in two requests. One for your main page and all the partial included without ajax, and one for your ajax-call. The ajax-call will not be dependent on the request for your mainpage, excluding it from the document.ready event that runs in your main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your index-script tag:**

```
function Initiate_Dialog(){
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
            title: 'Add Student',
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 650,
            show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,

            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("/Projekti/UnosuProjekat")
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },

            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
        return false;
}
```

**In your ajax.actionlink**

Add ajaxoptions, that allows you to run javascript OnSuccess. This should then call the Initiate_Dialog function.